# parsing different format of data in web page

Tags: html, web, scrapy

I was scraping a website and i came across this kind of data.

```
SA÷1¬~ZA÷ALBANIA: Superliga - Relegation - Play Offs¬ZEE÷nwPDBpVc¬ZB÷17¬ZY÷Albania¬ZC÷OjeYsUsT¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷OKzcNHo0¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷2¬ZH÷17_nwPDBpVc¬ZJ÷116¬ZL÷/football/albania/superliga/¬OAJ÷8tq6ua7j-xUYkC0EP.png¬ZX÷00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga - 034y Offs000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷Albania¬~AA÷rk90wXse¬AD÷1622383200¬ADE÷1622383200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Kastrioti¬ER÷Final¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622389894¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷KAS¬AE÷Kastrioti¬JA÷465nsFeG¬WU÷kastrioti¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬BY÷2¬GRA÷0¬AG÷2¬BA÷1¬BC÷1¬OA÷xSOynMU0-AJl2i8F3.png¬WN÷TOM¬AF÷Tomori Berat¬JB÷tWSFPnQr¬WV÷tomori-berat¬GRB÷0¬AH÷1¬BB÷0¬BD÷1¬OB÷U1UHfgU0-0G5ftKF1.png¬~ZA÷ALBANIA: Superliga¬ZEE÷nwPDBpVc¬ZB÷17¬ZY÷Albania¬ZC÷ULkLo4dK¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷OKzcNHo0¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷17_nwPDBpVc¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/football/albania/superliga/¬OAJ÷8tq6ua7j-xUYkC0EP.png¬ZX÷00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga   009erliga000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷Albania¬~AA÷zaI0bBX4¬AD÷1622041200¬ADE÷1622041200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Bylis¬ER÷Round 36¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622047958¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷BYL¬AE÷Bylis¬JA÷z1GsaTfk¬WU÷bylis¬GRA÷0¬AG÷2¬BA÷1¬BC÷1¬OA÷I5Lf42iT-YBGhZTz4.png¬WN÷PAR¬AF÷Partizani¬JB÷UNFobmAe¬WV÷partizani¬AS÷2¬AZ÷2¬GRB÷0¬AH÷4¬BB÷1¬BD÷3¬OB÷KMUe5pUH-K4OqaAaN.png¬~AA÷K2n5e9HN¬AD÷1622041200¬ADE÷1622041200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷KF Tirana¬ER÷Round 36¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622047889¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷TIR¬AE÷KF Tirana¬JA÷tKY8221s¬WU÷kf-tirana¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬GRA÷0¬AG÷3¬BA÷2¬BC÷1¬OA÷6J7hyple-YFxEiSIs.png¬WN÷SKE¬AF÷Skenderbeu¬JB÷zsYC1MGm¬WV÷skenderbeu-korca¬GRB÷0¬AH÷1¬BB÷1¬BD÷0¬OB÷6uRmtaCN-0G5ftKF1.png¬~AA÷txJdaiIb¬AD÷1622041200¬ADE÷1622041200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Kukesi¬ER÷Round 36¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622047759¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷KUK¬AE÷Kukesi¬JA÷6oQB4kXR¬WU÷kukesi¬GRA÷0¬AG÷1¬BA÷0¬BC÷1¬OA÷fDGm9QCN-U3kfxBO8.png¬WN÷KAS¬AF÷Kastrioti¬JB÷OQCw09uq¬WV÷kastrioti¬AS÷2¬AZ÷2¬GRB÷0¬AH÷2¬BB÷1¬BD÷1¬OB÷xSOynMU0-AJl2i8F3.png¬~AA÷tCm1dk2H¬AD÷1622041200¬ADE÷1622041200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Teuta¬ER÷Round 36¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622048076¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷TEU¬AE÷Teuta¬JA÷zL6yLAH8¬WU÷teuta¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬GRA÷0¬AG÷6¬BA÷2¬BC÷4¬OA÷d6TJntiT-jBP4UoqM.png¬WN÷APO¬AF÷Apolonia Fier¬JB÷Us6uKUWE¬WV÷apolonia-fier¬AK÷2¬GRB÷0¬AH÷1¬BB÷1¬BD÷0¬OB÷xE6xEmgT-v74buvV7.png¬~AA÷EkH4cVnB¬AD÷1622041200¬ADE÷1622041200¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Vllaznia¬ER÷Round 36¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622047996¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷VLL¬AE÷Vllaznia¬JA÷8EEkc7P1¬WU÷vllaznia¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬GRA÷0¬AG÷2¬BA÷1¬BC÷1¬OA÷MT7vPNoe-z5KryiaI.png¬WN÷LAC¬AF÷Laci¬JB÷dU7XLj22¬WV÷laci¬GRB÷0¬AH÷0¬BB÷0¬BD÷0¬OB÷2ogjpF86-tYT2wDC2.png¬AW÷1¬~ZA÷ALBANIA: Superliga - Relegation - Play Offs¬ZEE÷nwPDBpVc¬ZB÷17¬ZY÷Albania¬ZC÷OjeYsUsT¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷OKzcNHo0¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷2¬ZH÷17_nwPDBpVc¬ZJ÷116¬ZL÷/football/albania/superliga/¬OAJ÷8tq6ua7j-xUYkC0EP.png¬ZX÷00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga - 034y Offs000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷Albania¬~AA÷C0JtI07q¬AD÷1622037600¬ADE÷1622037600¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Burreli¬ER÷Semi-finals¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1622044279¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷BUR¬AE÷Burreli¬JA÷f70zV0LG¬WU÷burreli¬GRA÷0¬AG÷1¬BA÷0¬BC÷1¬OA÷4bLPEF86-ttSkQ5rb.png¬WN÷TOM¬AF÷Tomori Berat¬JB÷06O3DYkq¬WV÷tomori-berat¬AS÷2¬AZ÷2¬BZ÷1¬GRB÷0¬AH÷2¬BB÷1¬BD÷1¬OB÷U1UHfgU0-0G5ftKF1.png¬~ZA÷ALBANIA: Superliga¬ZEE÷nwPDBpVc¬ZB÷17¬ZY÷Albania¬ZC÷ULkLo4dK¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷OKzcNHo0¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷17_nwPDBpVc¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/football/albania/superliga/¬OAJ÷8tq6ua7j-xUYkC0EP.png¬ZX÷00Albania     007lbania0000000000001000Superliga
```

I don't know what the format is but i need this data. I am not using splash of selenium or anything since that will defeat the purpose of using scrapy anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want help, next time [include the target URL](https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/superliga/) as your opacity doesn't protect your source and just makes it harder on anyone trying to help you

Sniffing around in the HAR of the whole request, one can see they have a deciphering scheme present in `https://www.flashscore.com/x/js/core_2_1933000000.js`:

```js
...
,LeagueItemImpl.prototype.getTournamentId=function(){return this.getValue("ZE")}
,LeagueItemImpl.prototype.getTournamentStageId=function(){return this.getValue("ZC")}
```

and so forth

It doesn't appear to be an "encryption" per se, but is for sure designed to stop casual observers from just `json.loads` and being off to the races

It would take some study to find the actual meaning of those characters, but that payload appears to use `\u00ac` as the row separator, and `\u00f7` as the key-value separator, with `\u007e` playing an unknown role (there could quite literally be a field named `~ZA` and thus it's not that `~` plays any special role; that's why I said it would require further study)

Comment: hi, Thanks a TON for helping me out. I would definitely add the url and everything next time. It was my first time using stackoverflow and i loved your help.

Comment: i figured out the delimiters right here
   this.DELIMITER_ROW = "~",
   this.DELIMITER_CELL = "¬",
   this.DELIMITER_VALUE = "÷",